# c++ program to read single column of excel data containing two double values separated by a comma and store each in their own arrays

Tags: c++, excel

I have an excel file in which there is a single column with one double value, a comma, and then another double value in each cell.
ex:  5.393,4.1245

I would like to be able to read in those values and store them in separate arrays.  One array with x values and one array with y values so that I can do other things with them.

```
// string to be read from excel
string s1;

// declare object
ifstream input;

// open workbook
input.open("Workbook3.csv");

// check if file exists
if(input.fail())
{
    cout << "File does not exist." << endl;
    cout << "Exiting Program." << endl;
    return 0;
}

while(getline(input, s1, ','))
{
    // using this format I would need to convert string to double perhaps and then read into array?
}

return 0;
```

The trouble I'm having is figuring out how to read in a double value until a comma delimiter is reached and then reading in another value after the delimiter.  Following that, also telling it to move on to the next row until it would eventually reach an empty cell. Perhaps it would be a better idea to use VBS for this?
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can try with stringstream or some CSV parser. CSV is not a native Excel format.

Comment: I will try both of those options at some point today and let you know if it works, thanks!

Comment: I'm sad to say this is the inevitable consequence of ever higher abstraction and improvements and ease in programming. Even now, you probably want some C++ library that does what you want instead of rolling this yourself. The essence, young coder, of C/C++ is that it is native and more powerful. But, you should realize that means all you really have then is an adding machine and image creator. Pretty much, I'm saying you have to begin at first principles.

Comment: If you use `getline` with a comma character then the second read will contain two numbers separated by a newline, use `getline` with the new line character then copy the string to another string, `tempIn` until you find a comma.then use `stod()` passing it `tempIn` to convert to `double` and add the double to a `vector<double>` , then fill `tempIn` with null characters and read past the comma to the end of the line (the new line character) until you read the second double into `tempIn`, then convert it and store it in the Y vector.

Comment: btw, I'm only here because I thought someone wanted to know how to read XLSX files in C++, but it looks you are only reading a CSV, still if you want to know how to read an XLSX using Microsoft ODBC, I will answer.

Comment: Thank you Motes.  Originally it was an excel file but it seemed that changing the file type would make things easier with my limited knowledge.  The data acquisition application I'm using allows me to select the file type I want to save the data in so i changed from XLSX to CSV and then to LVD since the person's solution who commented below seemed to work with text files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the file is simply a text file in the format of double,double\n you could use the following code to read it into two arrays:

```
    std::vector<double> xs;
std::vector<double> ys;

while(getline(input,s1))
{
    std::istringstream ss(s1);
    double x, y;

    ss >> x;
    // read past the comma
    ss.get();

    ss >> y;

    //add to the arrays
    xs.push_back(x);
    ys.push_back(y);
}
```

This handles reading the comma and end of line with getline. Providing no delim argument assumes read to end of line.

Then create a string stream that treats a string somewhat like a file and allows you to parse the string like a file stream. Its not the fastest way to do this, but its simple and handles end of file and end of line in a simple way.

Comment: I made the software save as LVD instead and used your solution and it works! thank you very much.

Comment: Not a problem. Happy to help!